# How do I set inline styles in internet explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

In all other browsers, element.style seems to work fine. 
But Internet Explorer 8 doesn't know it...

Getting this error when x is a div:

```
Error: 'x.style.left' is null or not an object
```

x.style itself is undefined.  I looked at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html but it doesn't say anything about styles on specific elements, just like http://help.dottoro.com/ljuefnvw.php doesn't say anything either.

Comment: Can you show the actual JS code you are using?

Comment: Did the element have a style before? Is `x.style` null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div id="example">
    Test
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('example').style.marginLeft = '50px';
</script>
```

works

Comment: Tom, you are right. There must be some other problem. Debugging in IE8 is horrible :/. This is the exact line causing the problem: parseInt(x[0].style.left);, where x is a wrapper around the actual dom element.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using element.style, use the specific tag name.